# Hover over row event not firing in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, ag-grid

I'm attempting to fire an event each time a user hovers over an ag-grid row.

`cellMouseOver` is event that appears to provide this functionality ( src : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/ )

Here is my plunkr :

https://plnkr.co/edit/hgZp4pftfqjqpN7WghKA?p=preview

The issue is each time row is hovered over the cellMouseOver event is not fired. Is `cellMouseOver` event correct event to try in this case ? If not how should event be triggered when user hovers over a row ?

plunkr src :

example.js :

```
// specify the columns
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
];

// specify the data
var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    cellMouseOver : cellMouseOver,
    rowData: rowData,
    onGridReady: function (params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};

function cellMouseOver(event){
  console.log(event)  
}

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script> var __basePath = ''; </script>
<style> html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; } </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@17.0.0/dist/ag-grid.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 131px; width:600px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>

    <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `onCellMouseOver: cellMouseOver`?